# r - GNU Octave - prod & size in for loop for GNU Octave-compatible numel function in R

Tags: r, octave

I am working on a numel function that is GNU Octave/MATLAB(R) compatible (both the numel functions in pracma and matlab are not fully compatible).

I am using the FreeMat numel.m code for reference in creating the R numel function, this code follows:

```
function len = numel(x,varargin)
if (nargin==1)
  len = prod(size(x));
else
  len = 1;
  for k=1:length(varargin)
    len = len * numel(varargin{k});
  end
end
```

In the comments section of the numel.m code, this information is provided:

> "Generally, numel returns `prod(size(x))`, the number of total elements in x. However, you can specify a number of indexing expressions for `varagin` such as index1, index2, ..., indexm. In that case, the output of numel is `prod(size(x(index1,...,indexm)))`."

I have been able to implement all of the numel.m code in R, except for the `for` loop. The expression in the FreeMat for loop is a wrapper for the last statement in the quote above.

How do I implement this statement

```
prod(size(x(index1,...,indexm))
```

in R using the pracma `size` function?

Thank you.

For an example once the numel R code is complete, the following should work:

```
library(pracma)
a <- 1
b <- ones(2, 3)
numel(a, b)
# 6 / in both GNU Octave and R
```

I am enclosing the numel function below.

```
library(pracma)

numel <- function (x, ...)
{

if (nargs() == 1) {

    lens <- prod(size(x))

} else {

    varargin <- (nargs()-1L)

    len <- 1

    lens <- vector("list", Length(varargin))

    n <- 1:Length(varargin)
```

The code, as written, does not work as expected once the `for` loop runs. The question posed above was asked to fix the code that follows.

```
 for (k in n) {

    k <- as.array(k)

    lens[k] <- len * prod(size(k))   
# where size is defined in pracma::size
}
}
    lens
}
```

The following is the Length function (based on the FreeMat length.m function and further specifications in GNU Octave). The Length function is used in the numel function.

```
Length <- function (x)
{
if (isempty(x))

    Length <- 0

else if (length(is.vector(x)) == 1)

    Length <- 1

else if (is.vector(x))

    Length <- length(x)

else (is.matrix(x))

    Length <- max(size(x))

    return(Length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
numel <- function (x, ...)
{

if (nargs() == 1) {

  lens <- prod(size(x))

} else {

  varargin <- list(...)

  len <- 1

  lens <- vector("list", Length(varargin))

for (k in 1:Length(varargin)) {

  lens[[k]] <- len * size(varargin[[k]])
}

lens <- prod(unlist(lens))

}
return(lens)
}
```